# Basic Python imports question

Tags: python, import, python-3.x

If I have a src directory setup like this:

```
main.py
pkg1:
    __init__.py
    util.py
pkg2:
    __init__.py
    test.py
```

Can you tell me the best way to import `pkg1.util` from `main.py` and from `test.py`?

Thanks! (If I need to have another `__init__.py` file in the root directory, let me know?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention that this is Python 3, you do not have to add the following to your `.py` files.  I would still though because it helps backwards portability if some poor sod who's stuck on Python 2 needs to use your code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Given that you are using Python 3, or that you're using Python 2 and have included the above line, here is your answer:

From `main.py`:

```
import pkg1.util as util
```

from `test.py` you would use one of two ways depending on whether you considered `pkg1` and `pkg2` to be things that would always deployed together in the same way in relation to each other, or whether they will instead always be each deployed semi-independently at the top level.  If the first, you would do this:

```
from ..pkg1 import util
```

and if it's the second option, this:

```
import pkg1.util as util
```

This implies, of course, that you are always running Python from the directory in which `main.py` is, or that that directory is in `PYTHONPATH` or ends up in `sys.path` for some reason (like being the main Python site-packages directory for example).

Comment: If a different `pkg1` exists for some reason in `PYPATH`, will I still get *this* `pkg1` imported with both of these options?

Comment: @aharon: There is no option that promises you that you will get the intended `pkg1` without messing with `sys.path` yourself to make sure the appropriate directory is first in the path.  Having conflicting package names in this way is a very bad idea unless you have a package management system like `setuptools` that's managing the package as a 'namespace package'.

Comment: Won't all this require an `__init__py` in the same directory as `main.py`?  As it is, `test.py` and `util.py` are in completely separate packages which are not subpackage of a common superpackage.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I was assuming that `main.py` was a top-level package that wasn't in any sub-package when I gave my answer, but you make a good point.

Answer (score 1):

From main.py:

```
import pkg1.util
```

From test.py:

```
from ..pkg1 import util
```