# import class problem

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Python imports question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771475/basic-python-imports-question)

i have project with this structure:

```
project_folder:
    __init__.py
    classes_folder:
        __init__.py
        class1.py
        class2.py
    tests_folder:
        __init__.py
        test1.py
```

Now i need import `class1.py` in `test1.py`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `PYTHONPATH=.` and you are located in `project folder` then ...

`import classes_folder.class1`

By "located" I mean that you're running python from `project folder`.

it's all relative to your `PYTHONPATH`. Take that into account.

So if you are located in `project folder/tests_folder` in order to avoid issues make `PYTHONPATH` absolute to the root of your project:

`export PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/project_folder`

and then you won't have any problem when you launch your tests from a different folder.

**edit to answer comment on changing python path on runtime**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/full/path/to/project_folder")
```

or even better you could do it based on where from you execute python ...

```
import sys,os
home_project=os.path.abspath(".")
sys.path.append(home_project)
```

Comment: how can i add `project_folder` to `pythonpath` directly from script? I need possibility to simply copy `project_folder` to another computer and run `test` script without any pre-configurations

Comment: @cru3l see my edition of the answer. I have included what you might need.

Comment: that's work, but should i write this `sys.path.append` on top of every test script? is there a way to DRY this? thanks.

Comment: you need to do it just once on your "main" method. If you have a script that passes all the tests you just have to do it there.

Answer (score 1):

```
from ..classes_folder import class1
```

Example:

```
$ ls -R root
root:
foobar/  tests/  __init__.py

root/foobar:
__init__.py  mod.py

root/tests:
__init__.py  test1.py

$ cat root/foobar/mod.py; echo '###'; cat root/tests/test1.py
print "running", __name__
###
from ..foobar import mod

$ python -m root.tests.test1
running root.foobar.mod
```

Comment: that gives me `ValueError: 'Attempted relative import in non-package'`

Comment: @cru3l: How is test1 getting executed or imported?  You have not run test1.py as project_folder.tests_folder.test1, which is exactly the type of error this style of importing detects.

Comment: `?> pwd` -> `/Users/cru3l/project_folder/tests_folder/` , `?> python test1.py` -> `from ..classes_folder import class1 ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: @cru3l: Yes, that's the wrong way to do it.  See how I used python -m; you'll either need to be in the directory above 'project_folder'/'root' (which is usually nested down one more level, e.g. /Users/cru3l/project_name/name_of_top_package, where name_of_top_package might be the same as project_name), or 'project_folder'/'root' will have to be properly located in sys.path (which can happen a few different ways).

Comment: that's seems like a horrible way for me, because i want to work with independent script file, and that's way force me to run files as part of big project.

Comment: @cru3l: If they are independent scripts, move them out of the project package.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code to `classes_folder/__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['class1', 'class2']
```

Then in your test (`test_folder/test1.py`):

```
from classes_folder import *
```

This way `test1.py` will reach all your classes within `classes_folder`

Comment: that gives an error `ImportError: 'No module named classes_folder'`

Comment: ok. set PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/project_folder